# Test Internet Connection iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, connection

I'm using Reachability by Tony Million.

I have a Connection.m class that I have the following function:

```
+ (void)testBasicInternetConnection {

    Reachability *internetReachability;
    internetReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];

    //Internet is not reachable
    internetReachability.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach) {
        //Alert the user
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Attention" message:@"You are not connected to the internet. Please check your connection" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        });
    };

    //Internet is reachable
    internetReachability.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reach) {
        NSLog(@"Internet Access: SUCCESSFUL");
    };

    [internetReachability startNotifier];}
```

What I really want to be able to do is return a BOOL of unreachable or reachable from that function.

So, in my ViewController, I'd like to do something like this:

```
if ([Connection testBasicInternetConnection]) {
    [self logIn];
}
```

I'm stuck on how to get it to return that BOOL.

Thanks.

Comment: use reachablity in appdelegate and implement delegates there. create a flag in appdelegate and chech that flag in your viewController.change flag in rechachablitychanged in appdelegate. or use it in your connection class

Comment: -(void)reachabilityChanged:(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags)flags implement this method

Comment: Look here:https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability/blob/master/Reachability.h, it has `-(BOOL)isReachable;` `-(BOOL)isReachableViaWWAN;` `-(BOOL)isReachableViaWiFi;` functions.

Comment: @gabbler  - I saw those. I believe the issue in using just those is the unreachableBlock and reachableBlock are of course not being completed right away, so the if (isReachable) {}  will just fail every time since it hasn't been completed.

Comment: Refer to this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-detecting-network-changes-with-reachability--mobile-18299, it has a reachability manager created when app launches, and start monitoring, then in your separate controller, you can get the status right away.

Comment: @gabbler  Thanks! I followed along with that and I have it working for the most part. Not sure if it's just my device or if the check is happening before the ReachabilityManager finishes it's check. But, sometimes I get my alert saying no internet connection on my if( [ReachabilityManager isReachable]) in my viewDidLoad() on my main ViewController. It's random...

Comment: Yes, it is more possible that the manager hasn't finishes it's check, make sure you start monitoring as early as possible.

Comment: Yep. I start it right in my AppDelegate's   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions{}

Comment: This can be done easily with Apple Reachability. Any reason not to use it?

Comment: It takes sometime for the manager to check for isReachable, no matter what the connection status is, you take the person to login, if there is no connection, it will fail eventually.